# SQLite database Text column parser to double

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wanted to query my SQLite db and query the cost, which is TEXT in SQLite.
But I want to sum of the column value.

How do I do it?
Here's my code

```
public class estimate extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHandler db;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estimate);
        db=new DatabaseHandler(this);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setText("joma="+getJoma()+"");

    }
    public double getJoma(){

        Double sum=0.0;
        SQLiteDatabase dt = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = dt.rawQuery("select cost from TB where type=জমা",null);

        do{
            sum =sum+ Double.parseDouble(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("cost")));
        }
        while(res.moveToNext());
      return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply use INTEGER instead of TEXT

Comment: But i have floating value in DB....if int ..how can calculate floating?

Comment: When I parsing Text to double App unfortunately close

Comment: Then use REAL, instead of TEXT. https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: The problem is that the text values have a wrong format.

Comment: add a line before the `sum = sum+...` line, that outputs the cost as a string e.g. `Log.d("DBCOST,res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("cost"));` rerun the app and then edit your question to include the logged output.